# Jruby on Mountain Lion

Tags: java, gcc, jruby, osx-mountain-lion, rbenv

I have installed rbenv an am successfully running

ruby 2.0.0dev (2013-02-08 trunk 39161) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]

as shown through terminal using "ruby -v"

However, in trying to add any jruby-1.7.x using both "ruby-build" or "rbenv install" it get this:

```
BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/b2/1nykqqwd3934197qf_3vm1y80000gn/T/ruby-build.20130423121331.57961
Results logged to /var/folders/b2/1nykqqwd3934197qf_3vm1y80000gn/T/ruby-build.20130423121331.57961.log

Last 10 log lines:
rm -f build/unix/Darwin/argparser.o.d
g++ -O2 -Wall  -I'/Users/donaldtyson/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.1/include'   -c argparser.cpp -MMD -MP -MF build/unix/Darwin/argparser.o.d -o build/unix/Darwin/argparser.o
make[2]: g++: Bad CPU type in executable
make[2]: *** [build/unix/Darwin/argparser.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/donaldtyson/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/jruby-launcher-1.0.15-java for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/donaldtyson/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/jruby-launcher-1.0.15-java/./gem_make.out
```

I suspect something is wrong with my installation of Java or GCC

Comment: Where did your GCC/g++ come from? Do you have Xcode or its command line tools installed, or did you use something like Reitz's installer?

Comment: Installed gcc using homebrew. I do have xcode updated and with command line tools installed.

Comment: It's possible the Homebrew GCC is at fault, but I would expect that to be, if anything, x86_64 only; so I don't know what explains the "Bad CPU type". Maybe you installed a cross-compiler?